# Kubuntu 20.04 plasma desktop does not start after login

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, plasma-5

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04, only 2 days old. I just installed some apps that I use and configured KDE to my liking.

The system starts up quickly and I see the login screen, but when I enter my password, it shows the loading screen for a long time (earlier it was 2-3 seconds, now it is 30 seconds), then I just see the background wallpaper, a cursor and nothing else. No panel, no icons, nothing. However, keyboard shortcuts (i.e.: print screen) seems to be working.

There was this issue once in the past 2 days, but then a simple reboot solved it. Sadly this became permanent.

I can login on the console pressing ALT+F2.
Tried **kquitapp5 plasmashell** but it gave an error:
"Quitting the application plasmashell failed. org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply"

killall plasmashell worked, but then

**kstart5 plasmashell** gave the following error:
*"qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."*

I tried the reinstall with  **sudo apt-get reinstall xcb** but it did not solve the issue.

Rebooting no longer solves the issue. Also tried to run the system with an earlier kernel to no avail. I suspect this is just some user setup, probably regarding to multimonitor setup, as when I login and get the empty desktop, my secondary monitor setup is incorrect. It is pivoted, but the system uses it like it was in portrait mode. When the issue first arised, after the reboot, I had to reconfigure my display setup.

Earlier, I had Linux Mint 17.2 on this machine, never experienced such an issue.

My system is a B250 motherboard with a G4600 CPU, Nvidia GT 730. The system runs on an NVMe Samsung SSD and boots with EFI. I also have 3 HDDs and an additional older SATA SSD (yes, I have a lot of partitions)

Can I just reset the KDE config so the desktop would work? I really do not want to reinstall the whole system again.
Honestly, I just chose Kubuntu because Linux Mint ditched KDE and I don't like Cinnamon or Mate

**Edit:** I found the cause of the issue: I had the "Automatic mounting of removable media" enabled. When I swirched this off, the error disappeared.
Now I have a couple of partitionas I want to use and it's bothersome to manually mount them after each login. Should I just use fstab?

Comment: And how did you disable the automatic mounting feature without a GUI?

Comment: Once in about 10 restarts, I reached the GUI so I could switch this off.
Other than that, I think it can be switched off by removing the config file.

Comment: I thought you might have known which config file. Deleting it seems excessive, you can edit them in a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F2-F5).

Comment: I found it might get login loop if the `/` mounted disk is full. However login to `root` user doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on my Kubuntu 20.04 (i7-9750H + GTX1650 4GB) and I've found a solution that worked for me. Type ALT+F2 to go on your virtual console and login, then type :

```
sudo service sddm stop
rm ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
sudo service sddm start
```

Then I went back to my desktop and everything was back to normal. The solution that inspired me is here : https://superuser.com/questions/1131728/kde-taskbar-missing

Answer (score 0):

Even I have a fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04 (Ryzen 3550h + GTX1050 3GB).
The hack the works for me is

`sudo killall sddm`

on console pressing CTRL+ALT+F2.
No problem booting from power source but only appears while booting on battery .

The problem first started appearing when I uninstalled proprietary Nvidia Drivers (440). And maybe to retain your animations, using compositor as XRender helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got a blank screen right after the grub menu after recently installing kubuntu.
ctl-alt-f1 didn't do anything but ctl-alt-f2 brought up a cli.
'sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm' and selecting gdm3 as display manager seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and deleting that file `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` solved it for a while so that the desktop became accessible. I had suspected some widgets but with a basic panel the problem re-appeared.

I think the real cause was a setting in "Removable Devices" where ALL removable media had been selected. If one has too many that can cause problems I think. It's better to uncheck that and select devices manually - in case you want devices mounted at startup, like for using a sync tool etc.

[image]

Comment: The cause may vary but  on several occasions I was able to start normally after deleting the `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` file. This can be done by booting with a live Linux usb. It will reset the panel configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, none of the solutions worked.

I tried switching the login display manager with this command.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

Then I choice `lightdm` on the dropdown and the login started working.

I can still choose the plasma desktop after typing my password. So just the login screen became `lighthdm` style instead of `sddm` style.